# Call JS function on script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement Trulioo to a React application. Their documentation tells to put a `<script>` tag on the page, which will render their application form:

```
<div id="trulioo-embedid"></div>

<!-- This script renders the form for the div above --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.trulioo.com/latest/main.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize your form here with your Frontend (FE) key -->
<script> 
  // Handle the response of EmbedID after form submits
  function handleResponse(e) { 
    console.log('handleResponse', e); 
  } 
  
  const publicKey = 'Trial Key (FE)_OR_Live Key (FE)'; // Public Key
  // const accessTokenURL = 'http://localhost:8080/trulioo-api/embedids/tokens';
  new TruliooClient({ 
    publicKey, 
    // accessTokenURL,
    handleResponse 
  });
</script>
```

I implemented it the React way:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import truliooConfig from '../../../config/tuliooConfig';

export default function CustomerSignup() {
    function handleResponse(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    const { publicKey, accessTokenURL } = truliooConfig;

    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://js.trulioo.com/latest/main.js';
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        /*new TruliooClient({
            publicKey,
            accessTokenURL,
            handleResponse,
        });*/

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []);

    return <div id="trulioo-embedid" />;
}
```

The script loads fine and it's appended to the DOM, but I need to call the `new TruliooClient({})` with the authentication parameters.

I'm not sure how to call it, since it's not defined in React.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Edit: adding

```
script.onload = function () {
            new TruliooClient({ publicKey: publicKey, accessTokenURL: accessTokenURL, handleResponse });
        };
```

won't work either, because `TruliooClient` is not defined, even though it is defined in the script

Comment: Trulioo's GitHub has an example: https://github.com/Trulioo/trulioo-react-sample-app

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes but it's archived. They switched to this new EmbedId

Comment: So look at the documentation for EmbedId. For example https://gateway-admin.trulioo.com/documentation/embedid shows how to install the SDK with npm. Most likely you need to use the npm package instead of a `<script>` tag from there CDN.

Comment: I did. The SDK is for nodejs backend, which I already installed. My problem is rendering the form in the frontend

Comment: I'm running out of suggestions. I'm not familiar with trulioo and am just googling to find things that might help you. I'll let you know if I find anything else. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I also Googled a lot, but I can't find any solution on how to implement it

Comment: You call it the same as you do when not in React. I'd probably add an `onload` event handler to the `script` element you created, and put the constructor in that. If you're using TypeScript, you'll need to find definition files for whatever this is, or write your own.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey but how can I call `TruliooClient` if this is not defined in React, only in the script I loaded? Calling `new TruliooClient()` won't work because `TruliooClient` is not defined

Comment: It will be defined once the script is loaded, right? So something like `script.onload = function () { new TruliooClient(); };` will call the constructor after it's been defined.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree with you, but for React the `TruliooClient` is still undefined. I think I would need to access the script location and then call the `TruliooClient`

Comment: @OtavioBonder What error do you get with both of the things you tried?

Comment: Did you try adding the `<script>` tag to your `index.html`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `Line 16:17:  'TruliooClient' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: The script is being added to the DOM. I don't need to add it in the `index.html` because I don't want to load it in every page. But the same problem would occur. I need a way to access the functions inside the script

Comment: @OtavioBonder You should add the entire error message to your question. Also, did you add the `<script>` tag to `index.html`?

Comment: I can't even compile the code, because React won't find the `TruliooClient` function

Comment: It's not React. It's TypeScript. React is a library - it has nothing to do with compilation. [As I said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528602/call-js-function-on-script-tag?noredirect=1#comment112338866_63528602) you have to find definition files or write your own. You'll also need to append the script to the DOM, as the answer has shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, to anybody looking for an answer to the same problem, I could make it work.

I had to create a function to execute after the script was loaded:

```
    function scriptLoaded() {
        new window.TruliooClient({
            publicKey,
            accessTokenURL,
            handleResponse,
        });
    }
```

And I called it inside the `useEffect`:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://js.trulioo.com/latest/main.js';
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = () => scriptLoaded();

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []);
```